# The Power Map is Surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order $n$. Show that the map from $G$ to $G$ defined by $g \mapsto g^k$ is surjective, where $n$ and $k$ are relatively prime.

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group of order $n$. Since $k$ is relatively prime to $n$, then we can have neither $n | k$ nor $k | n$ true. By Lagranges' theorem, we know that every subgroup of a finite group $G$ divides $|G|$. Hence, there cannot be a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $|H| = k$ (Note: slight abuse of notation, since $k$ could be negative). In particular, there cannot be any elements of order $k$, for then the order of the subgroup generated by this element would divide the order $G$.

Here is where I got stuck. My strategy is to suppose the map is not surjective and from this construct/find an element of order $k$. If the map is not surjective, then there exists an $x \in G$ such that for every $g \in G$, $g^k = x$ will not hold. When $g = x$, we have that $x^k \neq x$; in fact, we have $x^{mk} \neq x$ for all $m$, which says $x \notin \langle x^k \rangle$, if I am not mistaken. I am trying to spot the contradiction, but I am having difficulty.

**Note:** I have found another solution, but I would still like my approach (or some slight variation of it) to work, as this strategy came most naturally to me. So please do not offer a proof entirely different, unless of course my strategy will not at all; I would like to salvage it, if possible.

Comment: I remember this exercise is a classical one in group theory, and most proofs that I know doesn't use Lagrange's theorem. As a matter of fact, the hypothesis $\gcd(n,k)=1$ suggest you to use Bézout's lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there exists integers $a,b$ such that $an + bk = 1$, which is to say that $bk \equiv 1 \pmod n$.  Define $\phi:G \to G$ by $g \mapsto g^k$, and $\psi:H \to G$ by $g \mapsto g^b$.

It suffices to note that $\phi \circ \psi$ is the identity map.  Since $\phi$ has a right-inverse, it is surjective.

Comment: Wouldn't you want $\psi(g) = g^b$? Also, is there no way of salvaging my approach?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I can't think of a way to make your approach work, but I think it's probably possible.

Answer (score 3):

Call $\phi$ the power map. Since $\gcd(n,k)=1$, by Bézout's lemma there exists integers $a,b$ such that $an+bk=1$. Now, take $g\in G$, because $G$ has order $n$, then $g^n=1$, so $g^{an+bk}=g^{bk}$, i.e., $g^{bk}=g$. Thus, there is $g^{b}\in G$ such that $(g^{b})^k=g$. Hence, $\phi$ is surjective.